# How to switch out only a specfic "view" of the page in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have an index.html with an ng-view within the page at a specific region. I want to make it such that when I click on a button on the page, the ng-view switches to another view, but without having to define a new route or trigger a route change. The following options are what I am thinking:

A main controller around everything. Each region/view would have its own controller (subcontroller1 and subcontroller2). Main controller has the responsiblity of switching views when appropriate without route.

Is this the right train of thinking? Are there any examples of switching just a part of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question : no, you can't partially use ng-view. There is only one ng-view per angularjs app, and the ng-view switches to another view according to the router.

You can load specific part of a page by using ng-switch, so that only part of the DOM are loaded according to the value of the ng-switch : http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch

Probably the closest answer to your question is to have look at the ui-router, in order to use nested routing : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router